# Horizontal Scroll Views and focus in Android?

Tags: android, focus, scrollview

I want to have something like 10 ImageViews in a Horizontal Scroll view. At any point only one ImageView is present on the screen, and when you scroll, the next ImageView is automatically centered (kind of like switching Home screens). On the bottom there is a "Continue" button and when you tap it, the ImageView that is currently centered is what is passed to the next Intent.

I've looked into this and found little sign of something like this existing, except perhaps a SwipeView? Is there any way to achieve the above explained effect in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try use ViewPager http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html